# What's the problem with this question?

Tags: discussion

[How to create a new amazon ec2 instance with 30GB hard disk?](https://serverfault.com/questions/422757/how-to-create-a-new-amazon-ec2-instance-with-30gb-hard-disk#comment450974_422757)

I think it's a simple question with reasonable answers.

I know I can add ebs packet. What about if I want to increase the root package. What is wrong with the question?

Is it too obvious? Duplicate? What?

Answer (score 4):

Have you read the comments on your question? As originally posted it was unanswerable (insufficient information for us to point you to a solution).  Server Fault moves quickly, and incomplete questions are closed aggressively because they just tend to attract people taking guesses based on assumptions which may later prove invalid.
11 hours without the needed information is plenty of time for 5 of our users to come by and say "This can't be answered as-is, close it until it's fixed"

If you would like your question reopened you need to *edit the question* to include all the relevant details needed to help people solve the problem.  If the question is deemed "good enough to reopen" by a sufficient number of users it will be reopened.

---

On a related note, this sort of question (`Where is the option to change XXXX?`) is typically something you should be asking your vendor (Amazon) - one of the answers is even a link to the documentation Amazon provides.

We do try to be helpful pointing people at the documentation and offering hints on how to apply it, but there has been a massive upswing in people using Server Fault as "Tech Support for the Intertubes" lately, and our users are getting quicker to hit the close button on this sort of question to protect the overall quality of questions and answers on the site.

Comment: `there has been a massive upswing in people using Server Fault as "Tech Support for the Intertubes" lately`  Also, I moved into Systems Administration to get away from having to answer obvious questions from morons (or people to lazy to read the damn documentation) and not to field those questions from the global community.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Your recruiter lied to you if you thought that being a SysAd would get you away from stupid/lazy questions...

Comment: @gWaldo  I should have phrased that better... I meant from the user base.  I expected all the morons asking questions to be management, and all the lazy people to be asking questions to be... well, me.  Admittedly, that hasn't worked out very well, but still, show of hands - how many SAs got into this to answer dumb and/or lazy questions from the internet...?

Answer (score 2):

Both are specific to the use of a vendor support product. You should contact the vendor.

The short reason of why it was closed, is that 5 people thought it should be. While I somewhat disagree with the closing, the question seems to lack the research necessary to make it a quality question. Please have a look at our [FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq) and [How to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask) for some additional resources on how to improve your question.